# c# System.InvalidCastException when passing datatable to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, parameter-passing

I'm defining a UDT in my MS SQL Server 2012 DB and using that in a stored procedure in the database. I'm trying to call my stored procedure from my c# program and I'm getting an error. Here's my code:

This is the definition of my UDT:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udt_850File] AS TABLE(
    [strInbound850FromPharmacyFilename] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [strSenderID_ISA06] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [strReceiverID_ISA08] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [strInterchangeControlVersion_ISA12] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [strInterchangeControlNumber_ISA13] [nvarchar](9) NOT NULL,
    [chElementDelimiter] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [chComponentElementDelimiter] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [chSegmentTerminator] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [intTransmissionDate_GS04] [int] NOT NULL,
    [strVersionRelease_GS08] [nvarchar](12) NOT NULL,
    [strTransSetControl_ST02] [nvarchar](9) NOT NULL,
    [strPONumber_BEG03] [nvarchar](22) NOT NULL,
    [intPODate_BEG05] [int] NOT NULL,
    [strWholesalerAccountNum_N1BY04] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [dtFileCreatedDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

Here is my stored procedure definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ppisp_sp_850Files_Insert]
    @850FileData [dbo].[udt_850File] READONLY
AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @ReturnVal INT = 0

        MERGE INTO [dbo].[850Files] AS target
        USING @850FileData AS source
            ON source.[strInbound850FromPharmacyFilename] = target.[strInbound850FromPharmacyFilename]
            AND source.[strSenderID_ISA06] = target.[strSenderID_ISA06]
            AND source.[strReceiverID_ISA08] = target.[strReceiverID_ISA08]
            AND source.[strInterchangeControlVersion_ISA12] = target.[strInterchangeControlVersion_ISA12]
            AND source.[strInterchangeControlNumber_ISA13] = target.[strInterchangeControlNumber_ISA13]
            AND source.[chElementDelimiter] = target.[chElementDelimiter]
            AND source.[chComponentElementDelimiter] = target.[chComponentElementDelimiter]
            AND source.[chSegmentTerminator] = target.[chSegmentTerminator]
            AND source.[intTransmissionDate_GS04] = target.[intTransmissionDate_GS04]
            AND source.[strVersionRelease_GS08] = target.[strVersionRelease_GS08]
            AND source.[strTransSetControl_ST02] = target.[strTransSetControl_ST02]
            AND source.[strPONumber_BEG03] = target.[strPONumber_BEG03]
            AND source.[intPODate_BEG05] = target.[intPODate_BEG05]
            AND source.[strWholesalerAccountNum_N1BY04] = target.[strWholesalerAccountNum_N1BY04]
            AND source.[dtFileCreatedDateTime] = target.[dtFileCreatedDateTime]
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
            INSERT ([strInbound850FromPharmacyFilename]
                    , [strSenderID_ISA06]
                    , [strReceiverID_ISA08]
                    , [strInterchangeControlVersion_ISA12]
                    , [strInterchangeControlNumber_ISA13]
                    , [chElementDelimiter]
                    , [chComponentElementDelimiter]
                    , [chSegmentTerminator]
                    , [intTransmissionDate_GS04]
                    , [strVersionRelease_GS08]
                    , [strTransSetControl_ST02]
                    , [strPONumber_BEG03]
                    , [intPODate_BEG05]
                    , [strWholesalerAccountNum_N1BY04]
                    , [dtFileCreatedDateTime])
            VALUES (source.[strInbound850FromPharmacyFilename]
                    , source.[strSenderID_ISA06]
                    , source.[strReceiverID_ISA08]
                    , source.[strInterchangeControlVersion_ISA12]
                    , source.[strInterchangeControlNumber_ISA13]
                    , source.[chElementDelimiter]
                    , source.[chComponentElementDelimiter]
                    , source.[chSegmentTerminator]
                    , source.[intTransmissionDate_GS04]
                    , source.[strVersionRelease_GS08]
                    , source.[strTransSetControl_ST02]
                    , source.[strPONumber_BEG03]
                    , source.[intPODate_BEG05]
                    , source.[strWholesalerAccountNum_N1BY04]
                    , source.[dtFileCreatedDateTime]);

            SET @ReturnVal = @@ROWCOUNT
    END
```

Here is my c# class file where I define my datatable and populate it with data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace PP_ISP_File
{
    public class PP_ISP_File_Data 
    {
        public DataTable dt_Files_Info { get; set; }

        public PP_ISP_File_Data(string strFileDirectoryPath, int intFileType)
        {
            dt_Files_Info = new DataTable();
            dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("strSenderID_ISA06", typeof(string));
            dt_Files_Info.Columns["strSenderID_ISA06"].DefaultValue = default(string);
            dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("strReceiverID_ISA08", typeof(string));
            dt_Files_Info.Columns["strReceiverID_ISA08"].DefaultValue = default(string);
            dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("strInterchangeControlVersion_ISA12", typeof(string));
            dt_Files_Info.Columns["strInterchangeControlVersion_ISA12"].DefaultValue = default(string);
            dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("strInterchangeControlNumber_ISA13", typeof(string));
            dt_Files_Info.Columns["strInterchangeControlNumber_ISA13"].DefaultValue = default(string);
            dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("chElementDelimiter", typeof(char));
            dt_Files_Info.Columns["chElementDelimiter"].DefaultValue = default(char);
            dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("chComponentElementDelimiter", typeof(char));
            dt_Files_Info.Columns["chComponentElementDelimiter"].DefaultValue = default(char);
            dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("chSegmentTerminator", typeof(char));
            dt_Files_Info.Columns["chSegmentTerminator"].DefaultValue = default(char);
            dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("intTransmissionDate_GS04", typeof(int));
            dt_Files_Info.Columns["intTransmissionDate_GS04"].DefaultValue = -1;
            dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("strVersionRelease_GS08", typeof(string));
            dt_Files_Info.Columns["strVersionRelease_GS08"].DefaultValue = default(string);
            dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("strTransSetControl_ST02", typeof(string));
            dt_Files_Info.Columns["strTransSetControl_ST02"].DefaultValue = default(string);

            if(intFileType == 850)
            {
                dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("strInbound850FromPharmacyFilename", typeof(string));
                dt_Files_Info.Columns["strInbound850FromPharmacyFilename"].DefaultValue = default(string);
                dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("strPONumber_BEG03", typeof(string));
                dt_Files_Info.Columns["strPONumber_BEG03"].DefaultValue = default(string);
                dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("intPODate_BEG05", typeof(int));
                dt_Files_Info.Columns["intPODate_BEG05"].DefaultValue = -1;
                dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("strWholesalerAccountNum_N1BY04", typeof(string));
                dt_Files_Info.Columns["strWholesalerAccountNum_N1BY04"].DefaultValue = default(string);
            }
            else if(intFileType == 855)
            {
                dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("strOutbound855ToPharmacyFilename", typeof(string));
                dt_Files_Info.Columns["strOutbound855ToPharmacyFilename"].DefaultValue = default(string);
                dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("strPONumber_BAK03", typeof(string));
                dt_Files_Info.Columns["strPONumber_BAK03"].DefaultValue = default(string);
                dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("intPODate_BAK04", typeof(int));
                dt_Files_Info.Columns["intPODate_BAK04"].DefaultValue = -1;
                dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("strWholesalerAccountNum_N1ST04", typeof(string));
                dt_Files_Info.Columns["strWholesalerAccountNum_N1ST04"].DefaultValue = default(string);
            }

            dt_Files_Info.Columns.Add("dtFileCreatedDateTime", typeof(DateTime));
            dt_Files_Info.Columns["dtFileCreatedDateTime"].DefaultValue = default(DateTime);

            dt_Files_Info = GetFileDetails(strFileDirectoryPath, intFileType);
        }

       private DataTable GetFileDetails(string strFileDirectoryPath, int intFileType)
        {
            DataTable dtPP_ISP_Files_Return = dt_Files_Info.Clone();

            DirectoryInfo diDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strFileDirectoryPath);

            if (diDirectoryInfo.Exists)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo fiFileInfo in diDirectoryInfo.GetFiles())
                {
                    if (fiFileInfo.Exists)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srFile = new StreamReader(fiFileInfo.FullName))
                        {
                            string strFileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fiFileInfo.FullName);
                            if (strFileData.Length >= 104)
                            {
                                DataRow dr = dtPP_ISP_Files_Return.NewRow();

                                char chElementDelimiter = default(char);
                                char chComponentElementDelimiter = default(char);
                                char chSegmentTerminator = default(char);

                                chElementDelimiter = Convert.ToChar(strFileData.Substring(3, 1));
                                dr["chElementDelimiter"] = chElementDelimiter;
                                chComponentElementDelimiter = Convert.ToChar(strFileData.Substring(104, 1));
                                dr["chComponentElementDelimiter"] = chComponentElementDelimiter;
                                chSegmentTerminator = Convert.ToChar(strFileData.Substring(105, 1));
                                dr["chSegmentTerminator"] = chSegmentTerminator;
                                dr["dtFileCreatedDateTime"] = File.GetCreationTime(strFileDirectoryPath);

                                string[] arrFileLines = strFileData.Split(Convert.ToChar(chSegmentTerminator));

                                for (int i = 0; i <= arrFileLines.Length - 1; i++)
                                {
                                    string[] arrLineData = arrFileLines[i].Split(Convert.ToChar(chElementDelimiter));
                                    string strLineQualifier = arrLineData[0].Trim();

                                    switch (strLineQualifier)
                                    {
                                        case "ISA":
                                            dr["strSenderID_ISA06"] = arrLineData[6].Trim();
                                            dr["strReceiverID_ISA08"] = arrLineData[8].Trim();
                                            dr["strInterchangeControlVersion_ISA12"] = arrLineData[12].Trim();
                                            dr["strInterchangeControlNumber_ISA13"] = arrLineData[13].Trim();
                                            break;
                                        case "GS":
                                            dr["intTransmissionDate_GS04"] = Convert.ToInt32(arrLineData[4].Trim());
                                            dr["strVersionRelease_GS08"] = arrLineData[8].Trim();
                                            break;
                                        case "ST":
                                            dr["strTransSetControl_ST02"] = arrLineData[2].Trim();
                                            break;
                                        case "BEG":
                                            dr["strInbound850FromPharmacyFilename"] = fiFileInfo.Name;                                            
                                            dr["strPONumber_BEG03"] = arrLineData[3].Trim();
                                            dr["intPODate_BEG05"] = Convert.ToInt32(arrLineData[5].Trim());
                                            break;
                                        case "BAK":
                                            dr["strOutbound855ToPharmacyFilename"] = fiFileInfo.Name;
                                            dr["strPONumber_BAK03"] = arrLineData[3].Trim();
                                            dr["intPODate_BAK04"] = Convert.ToInt32(arrLineData[4].Trim());
                                            break;
                                        case "N1":
                                            if(arrLineData[1].Trim() == "BY")
                                            {
                                                dr["strWholesalerAccountNum_N1BY04"] = arrLineData[4].Trim();
                                                dtPP_ISP_Files_Return.Rows.Add(dr);
                                            }
                                            else if (arrLineData[1].Trim() == "ST")
                                            {
                                                dr["strWholesalerAccountNum_N1ST04"] = arrLineData[4].Trim();
                                                dtPP_ISP_Files_Return.Rows.Add(dr);
                                            }
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return dtPP_ISP_Files_Return;
        }
    }
}
```

and lastly here is my code where I initialize my datatable and try to pass it to the stored procedure in my database:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSPName, con))
{
    PP_ISP_File_Data dtFileInfo = new PP_ISP_File_Data(strWatchPath, intFileType);

    cmd.CommandText = strSPName;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter spFilenames = new SqlParameter("@850FileData", SqlDbType.Structured);
    spFilenames.TypeName = "dbo.udt_850File";
    spFilenames.Value = dtFileInfo;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(spFilenames);

    SqlParameter returnParameter = new SqlParameter("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(returnParameter);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int result = Convert.ToInt16(returnParameter.Value);
}
```

Running my code gives me this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Failed to convert parameter value from a
>   PP_ISP_File_Data to a IEnumerable`1.'

I have a suspicion that because I'm declaring my datatable in a class file it's not getting something that it needs to be able to enumerate over it when it gets passed to the stored procedure but I don't know how to correct that. Can someone please point me in the right direction to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: which line is showing this error?

Comment: @suijth karivelil the line that reads cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: How about `spFilenames.Value = dtFileInfo.dt_Files_Info`? Certainly you cannot pass class object into `SqlDbType.Structured`, you need a `DataTable` or collections which convertible with `AsEnumerable()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to pass datatable as parameter to the stored procedure for it to be used as UDT but right now you are passing whole object of your class which will not work.

So change the following line:

```
spFilenames.Value = dtFileInfo;
```

to:

```
spFilenames.Value = dtFileInfo.dt_Files_Info;
```

[From MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters#configuring-a-sqlparameter-example):

> **System.Data.SqlClient** supports populating table-valued parameters from **DataTable**, **DbDataReader** or **IEnumerable \ SqlDataRecord** objects.

Also refer to [**Passing a Table-Valued Parameter to a Stored Procedure**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters#passing)

You can take a look at the following posts for more:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/06/01/table-valued-parameters.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: works like a charm, I knew I was missing something simple. Accepted as answer and tried to up vote but my reputation is too low for it to show. Thanks again!

Comment: glad that it helped.